# Kernel Compilation: Force all modules to be baked in

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, compile

I am building a kernel with OpenWrt for a hardware device. As there will no new pluggable hardware which will be added later, I want to make sure that all kernel modules are built into the kernel. This way I can disable module loading and stop cyber attacks which rely on loading code via modules.

My question- how can I force all selected modules to be automatically built statically into the kernel. I don't want to select the modules individually to make this change. I am looking for a shortcut.

Comment: Normally not recommended, but you could try editing the kernel's **.config** file, and replace all the `=m` to `=y`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do this all 3000+ modules will be built and embeded into your kernel.  Your kernel will be massively oversized.

This is a terrible idea, but:

```
make allyesconfig
```

You need to have the kernel source on the device in question temporarily.  Once you do a make localmodconfig you can copy the .config file to another machine, if you want, and compile it there.

What you should do is:

> make localmodconfig

Then edit the config file

.config

and do a search and replace for **m** replacing it with **y**

Now you will only have about 110 modules, and it will boot faster, and not be massively oversized.

Comment: Thanks! but is there a shortcut to changing the m to y? or is the manual edit the only way?

Comment: cat .config| sed 's/=m/=y/g' >.config2.  Move .config to a backup folder. rename .config2 .config

Comment: Thanks! Sorry don't have enough reputation to upvote this.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify cybernards answer even more:

`make localyesconfig` will do the same thing as `make localmodconfig`, execpt all the modules will be automatically marked as built-in!

See the kernel [readme](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/README) and this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253245/what-does-make-localmodconfig-do) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

so maybe this will this do the job.

run 'hwinfo' (hopefully enough to probe hardware as I think module need to be loaded and probing hardware will do it)
run 'make localyesconfig' in kernel dir
(Postulate: 'make localmodconfig' and 'make localyesconfig'  both use 'lsmod' to do their stuff)

You might want to chose yes for various stuff like filesystem (proc/config.gz, exfat, vfat and efi stuff can be a good idea) crypto and other more more passive stuff (non hardware) you know you need before your yes kernel by choosing yes on those too. Having /proc/config.gz' is a good idea for later recompiles.

Suggest you keep at least a hardened and an experiment kernel for boot and set the hardened as default in case you got keyboard/screen issues).